# Criando Ações(Jquery) exclusivas para um navegador

Tags: javascript, jquery, navegador-de-internet

Boa tarde!

Gostaria de saber se é possível criar uma function com o Jquery exclusiva para um navegador específico

Por exemplo:

```
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
     $("#imagens a").click(function(e) {
        var id = $(this).prop("id");
            id = "Imagens/foto"+id+".jpg";

         $(window).bind('scroll', setTopo);

         $("#img_principal").css('display','block');

         $("#img_principal").attr("src",id);    
    });

    $(".titulo").click(function(e) {
        $("#img_principal").css('display','none');
         $(window).unbind('scroll', setTopo);
    });  
});
```

Onde a minha function é:

```
   function setTopo(){
      $(window).scrollTop(2000);
    }
```

Eu queria que ao abrir no Firefox/Opera os valores(scrollTop) fossem outros mas com a mesma função, já que a estrutura que eu montei apresenta diferença quando executada nesses navegadores. Utilizei o Chrome como base e a partir dele comecei a adaptar em outros navegadores.

Grato

Comment: Sim isso é possivel, seria interessante explicares o problema e qual é o comportamento/tecnologia que dá resultados diferentes em browsers diferentes e assim ajudar-mos a normalizar os valores.

Comment: Ao abrir uma imagem eu queria que o scroll do mouse fosse bloqueado, então usei o 'scroll', função com o valor(px). O problema é que ao abrir em outro navegador o valor tem variação, nisso a imagem em questão aparece cortada ou fora de posição(já que o navegador trava no valor que informei).

Answer (score 0):

Você deve usar este código para identificar o navegador do usuário:

```
if (jQuery.browser.mozilla){
        // Seu código aqui se for o firefox seu navegador
    else if (jQuery.browser.msie){
        // Seu código aqui se for o Internet Explorer
    else if (jQuery.browser.safari){
        // Seu código aqui se for o Safari
    else if (jQuery.browser.opera){
        // Seu código aqui se for Opera
    } else {
        // Seu código aqui
});
```

Para o seu exemplo:

```
function setTopo(){
    if (jQuery.browser.mozilla){
        // Seu código aqui se for o firefox seu navegador
        $(window).scrollTop(2000);
   else if (jQuery.browser.msie){
        // Seu código aqui se for o Internet Explorer
        $(window).scrollTop(3000);
    else if (jQuery.browser.safari){
        // Seu código aqui se for o Safari
        $(window).scrollTop(4000);
    else if (jQuery.browser.opera){
        // Seu código aqui se for Opera
        $(window).scrollTop(5000);
    else {
        // Seu código aqui
        $(window).scrollTop(6000);
    })

}
```

Comment: Lembrando apenas que isso foi removido na [versão 1.9](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/) do jQuery.

Comment: Eu coloco toda a função? Eu encontrei algo parecido quando pesquisei, mas não consegui aplicar. Dentro de cada else if vai o comando que quero aplicar no navegador?

Comment: @Randrade - De fato estou utilizando a 1.12, existe alguma alternativa ou devo utilizar a versão mais antiga?

Comment: @A.LFreire, editei a pergunta, confira a resposta pra ver se é o que vc quer

Comment: @DavidDamasceno Acredito que seja isso, vou testar aqui

Comment: @A.LFreire Você pode usar o [jQuery Migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme) ou o `navigator.userAgent`

Comment: @Randrade Estava me informando em relação ao Migrate, voçê já o utilizou? É só linkar o migrate.js no site e os comandos antigos funcionam?